# Prevent event from being executed while another is being run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a portfolio section for my website where a background image fades in when a project name is being hovered and fades out when the cursor leaves the project name. This works fine, however the problem I am facing is that when I am rapidly hovering from one project name to another, the 'mouseenter' event is being triggered while the 'mouseleave' event is still running, waiting for the animation to finish.

Is there a way to prevent the 'mouseenter' event from being triggered while the 'mouseleave' event is still running?

I have set up a [codepen](http://codepen.io/joelmercier/pen/xOroKG) but it's not working correctly, is this a codepen limitation ? My [full code is available on Github](https://github.com/Joel-Mercier/portfolio) (requires Jekyll and Gulp).

Here is the code I am  using :

```
$('#barba__wrapper').on('mouseover', '.portfolio__link', function(event) {
  var currentImage = $('.portfolio__image--current');
  var portfolioImg = $(this).parent().data('img');
  var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
  currentImage.css('background-image', 'url('+ portfolioImg +')');
  currentImage.addClass('animated fade-in').one(animationEnd, function() {
   currentImage.removeClass('animated fade-in');
  });
});

$('#barba__wrapper').on('mouseleave', '.portfolio__link', function(event) {
  var currentImage = $('.portfolio__image--current');
  var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
  currentImage.addClass('animated fade-out').one(animationEnd, function() {
    currentImage.css('background-image', '');
    currentImage.removeClass('animated fade-out');
  });
});
```

Thank you for your time ! :)

Comment: So do you want to buffer and queue the moves? Even if 5 hovers happen in rapid succession, the user will have to wait while the interface catches up?

Comment: Couldn't you just swap the background with CSS and get rid of all the javascript, you seem to be using CSS animations anyway ?

Comment: Also, you should use `mouseenter`, not `mouseover`.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery's [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) methods instead? To stop animation use [stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/): `currentImage.stop().fadeIn()` and `currentImage.stop().fadeOut()`.

Comment: @Wes I dont want to queue them that would be a bad user experience it's just that if i rapidly switch between the links, the effect doesn't work correctly

Comment: @adeneo No because I want the fade in / fade out effect, also I heard that js animations are quite slower than the CSS ones even if jQuery seems to use CSS with these two functions. I also don't want the `display: none;` added by the fadeout function because it breaks my style

Comment: @skobaljic Right ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It a bit of an overkill but you could use a stack of event like this :

```
        var actionsStack = [];
var needWait = false;

var mouseOverAction = function(target){
  var currentImage = $('.portfolio__image--current');
  var portfolioImg = target.parent().data('img');
  var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
  currentImage.css('background-image', 'url('+ portfolioImg +')');
  currentImage.addClass('animated fade-in').one(animationEnd, function() {
   currentImage.removeClass('animated fade-in');
   needWait = false;
   handleStack();
  });
};

var mouseLeaveAction = function(target)
{
  var currentImage = $('.portfolio__image--current');
  var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
  currentImage.addClass('animated fade-out').one(animationEnd, function() {
    currentImage.css('background-image', '');
    currentImage.removeClass('animated fade-out');
    needWait = false;
   handleStack();
  });
};

var addAction = function(action, target)
{
    actionsStack.push({ action: action, target: target });
    handleStack();
};

var handleStack = function()
{
    if(actionsStack.length > 0 && !needWait)
    {
        needWait = true;
        var item = actionsStack.shift();
        item.action(item.target);
    }
};

$('#barba__wrapper').on('mouseover', '.portfolio__link', function(event) {
  addAction(mouseOverAction, $(this));
});

$('#barba__wrapper').on('mouseleave', '.portfolio__link', function(event) {
  addAction(mouseLeaveAction, $(this));
});
```

It basically add all the event function into a stack, and then consume this stack until it's empty.

Comment: Thanks the effect works correctly with your implementation I just expressed my question badly, I don't want to queue the events because if I rapidly go over the links, the image fades in and out many times. Is there a way to reset the stack on mouseleave ? Thank you very much though !

Comment: If you rewrite your script to use jquery animate function instead of css animation, you could simplye use clearQueue on mouse leave I guess...